# Internet Explorer 8 prototypes and XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, xmlhttprequest

This is partially a request for a workaround, and partially an attempt to get the word out that Internet Explorer's prototype implementation is still faulty.

The following code does not work on Internet Explorer.

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.old = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.old("POST", "test", false);
```

For IE 8 beta, and all previous versions, the XMLHttpRequest.prototype property never existed in the first place. In IE8, it does exist, but you'll get a "Invalid procedure call or argument" error. Internet Explorer doesn't like decoration.

Does anyone know of a workaround for this?

**Update**:

It has been pointed that I could override the entirety of XMLHttpRequest with a new function and constructor, and then create a wrapper script ala XMLHttpRequest.js. The prototype method is much shorter, so I would still prefer to use it for non-IE browsers.

Comment: Have you reported this to Microsoft?

Comment: Not yet. I'm not sure I have the patience to figure out Microsoft's bug reporting channels.

Comment: Would [this page](http://www.ilinsky.com/articles/XMLHttpRequest/) offer a solution?

Comment: Arguably using prototype to surgically override methods is much more elegant (30 lines versus 300 lines). That said, if I want to support IE, I'll probably have to do what that page suggests.

Comment: I wouldn't hurry, think I saw a report that got closed without comment.

Comment: I'd say that's the solution. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that IE 8 recognizes XMLHttpRequest, but not as a function.  Active X objects still seem to work.  Instead of testing for the existance of window.XMLHtppRequest, I test for the typeof window.XMLHtppRequest.  seems to work OK.

I recoded my get request as follows:

```
FG.ajax.getxhr = function(){
var xhr;
if (typeof window.XMLHttpRequest === 'function') {
    xhr  = XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
return xhr;
```